# There are n balls and m colors, calculate the ways that color 1 appear most

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Also, color 1 can be as many as others.

for example: there 2 balls and 3 colors, we can color like that:

1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 2 1, 2 2, 2 3, 3 1, 3 2, 3 3

and 1 1, 1 2, 1 3, 2 1, 3 1 are the valid answer, so the answer is 5.

but how to calculate with n,m?

Comment: Variations of this question have been asked several times in the last day or so. I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways that color 1 appear is $${N}= {m! \over (m-n)!}-{(m-1)! \over (m-n-1)!}+1$$ 
Where  A = ${m! \over (m-n)!} + m$ is the total number of possible combinations, 
 B = ${(m-1)! \over (m-1-n)!} + m -1$ is the total number of possible combinations with n balls and m-1 colors. 
The resulting formula gotten as $N = A - B$